# Conversion tracking code immediately after body tag?

Tags: commerce

I'm fairly new to Drupal, so bare with me. I need to add some tracking code immediately after the body tag on the checkout complete page. I'm guessing I need to add it to the html.tpl.php or `$page_top` variables or maybe a checkout pane. My question is:

1. Which way is the best way to do it?
2. If I need to add it in the html.tpl.php, how would I do that for just the checkout complete page?
3. If I need to add it in the `$page_top` variable for only the checkout complete page, how would I do that?
4. If I need to do it in a checkout pane, how would I keeping in mind is needs to be immediately after the body tag?

Using the Drupal Commerce module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in template.php by using [theme_preprocess_html()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $arg = arg();
  $vars['checkout_tracking_script'] = '';
  if (count($arg) == 3 && $arg[0] == 'checkout' && $arg[1] == 'complete' && is_numeric($arg[2])) {
    $vars['checkout_tracking_script'] = '<script>myScript</script>';
  }
}
```

Then in your html.tpl.php you can print your script like this.

```
<?php if ($checkout_tracking_script): ?>
  <?php print $checkout_tracking_script; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```